# How do I get the name of non null columns for each set of rows?

Tags: postgresql, null

Lets say I have this following table:

[image: Original database]

I want to get a table with the **non null columns** for each name that looks something like this:

[image: output]

I have hundreds of columns so listing all of them in the query is not possible. 
I'm working with `postgresql`.

Thanks

Comment: Retrieving a different set of colums on each line seems like a bad practice. You could use the `SELECT *` operator to retrieve every colum without having to list them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert rows to jsonb and aggregate keys with not null values in groups by name:

```
select name, array_agg(distinct key) as not_null_columns
from my_table t
cross join jsonb_each(to_jsonb(t)- 'name')
where value <> 'null'
group by name;

 name | not_null_columns 
------+------------------
 jake | {a,b,d}
 mike | {c,d}
 phil | {a,b,c}
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much!